# WordPress - Order by ACF date, date first, then empty fields last

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to order content by the dick picker provided by ACF.

- order by date field

  - Dates in order of soonest(past/present) to farthest out (ASC ordering).
  - Then any post that meets the criteria but doesn't have a date set would be last.

I have the following Query arguments:

```
(
    [post_type] => people
    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [paged] => 1
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => has_scheduling
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => custom_ID
                    [compare] => !=
                    [value] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [key] => date_picker
                    [compare] => !=
                    [value] => 
                )

        )

    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => people_types
                    [field] => term_id
                    [terms] => 153
                )

        )

    [meta_key] => date_picker
    [orderby] => meta_value_num
    [order] => ASC
)
```

I noticed that this Query will only load the first part correctly.  It grabs content based on all the parameters, then orders is by date, but it excludes the content that doesn't have a date set.

I've tried this as well:

```
(
    [post_type] => people
    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [paged] => 1
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => has_scheduling
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => custom_ID
                    [compare] => !=
                    [value] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => OR
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => date_picker
                            [compare] => EXISTS
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => date_picker
                            [compare] => NOT EXISTS
                        )

                )

        )

    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => people_types
                    [field] => term_id
                    [terms] => 153
                )

        )

    [orderby] => meta_value
    [order] => ASC
)
```

So here I don't exclude empty fields, I check if it exists and then doesn't.  Then order by the data again.  I also switched to use `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num`

Any tips or tricks, or if you have run into issue as well, I'd love to see what you did.

Comment: _"but it excludes the content that doesn't have a date set"_ - of course it does, you explicitly demanded that the `date_picker` must not be empty. And your second attempt is quite pointless - a condition "exists or not exists" is completely superfluous, because those are the only two possible options to begin with. A condition that covers _all_ possible cases, effectively doesn't limit the data selection at all, and can be removed completely, and you'd still get the same result.

Comment: _"Then any post that meets the criteria but doesn't have a date set would be last."_ - you "listed" this as your second criterion - but it should actually be the first. You want your posts ordered by whether or not the have a date set, first. And then, within that ordering, you want to sort them by date ascending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone also trying to do the same, the end result for this ended using a custom a `orderby` filter. Example code below.

```
// Order By custom date.
add_filter('posts_orderby', function (string $orderby, WP_Query $query) {
    if ($query->get('orderby') === '__custom_date__') {
        $orderby = "mta.meta_value is NULL, mta.meta_value ='', mta.meta_value ASC";
    }
    return $orderby;
}, 10, 2);

// Extra join to order by custom date.
add_filter('posts_join', function (string $join, WP_Query $query) {
    if ($query->get('orderby') === '__custom_date__') {
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mta ON ( wp_posts.ID = mta.post_id AND mta.meta_key = 'date_picker')";
    }
    return $join;
}, 10, 2);
```

This is then used as a parameter that gets passed to `orderby`

```
$args['orderby'] = '__custom_date__';
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick addendum to this;

My solution was a bit 'dirty' but quite simple.

I did a simple `orderby` so the blanks came first. When I stepped through the results I put them in a container with CSS `flex` and `flex-direction:column`. I could then give the blank dates the CSS `order:1000` and they appear at the end.